# Android-ndk output in Logcat irrecognizable

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, logcat

I am using ffmpeg with librtmp in my android project via jni. and the output from librtmp in Logcat looks like follows:

```
06-03 14:36:06.321: DEBUG/NDK_mmsplay(12736): Property: <�X�KI {DY������F�:>
06-03 14:36:06.321: DEBUG/NDK_mmsplay(12736): Property: NULL
06-03 14:36:06.321: DEBUG/NDK_mmsplay(12736): Property: <�X�KI {DY������F�:>
06-03 14:36:06.321: DEBUG/NDK_mmsplay(12736): Property: <�X�KI {DY������F�:>
06-03 14:36:06.321: DEBUG/NDK_mmsplay(12736): (object end)
06-03 14:36:06.321: DEBUG/NDK_mmsplay(12736): �X, server invoking <�KI {DY������F�:>
06-03 14:36:06.321: DEBUG/NDK_mmsplay(12736): �X: fd=-2135941431, size=-2133930231
```

any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Bolton

Comment: How do you output those strings? I had something similar

Comment: I was working on a project using librtmp with ffmpeg, which is targeted for the demux job for my android app through Jni. I set the rtmp log callback in ffmpeg and just got the output above:P

Comment: show your log handler implementation

Answer (score 0):

Have to be careful with the data types remember that:

> Java provides 8 "primitives" types: byte, short, int, long, float,
>   double, char, and boolean. These as the same as the following C++
>   typedefs (which are defined in a standard header file): jbyte, jshort,
>   jint, jlong, jfloat, jdouble, jchar, and jboolean.

Pay attention with C++ log functions.